# Java 8 reading file list, but files remain open using up resources till server freezes

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, java-8, scheduled-tasks

This is a copy of code that I run on a tomcat server on a scheduler. When I check the status of the server I can see the no of open files increasing

This is the command used to check open files

`sudo lsof -p $(pidof java) | grep "DIR" | wc -l`

This is an example of the code wrapped in a unit test.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class OpenFilesTest {

    @Test
    public void FileRemainOpen() throws IOException {
        String path = "/data/cache/hotels/from_ivector";

        List <String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

        Files.list(Paths.get(path))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .forEach(file -> {
                String name = file.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase();
                if (name.endsWith(".csv") || name.endsWith(".txt")) {
                    name = file.getFileName().toFile().getName();
                    files.add(name);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Eventually the resources run out and the server freezes.

Comment: What are you trying do to?

Comment: Have you tried using a [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) in combination with calling [`Files.walkFileTree(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-)?

Comment: Already have used an alternate solution for reading the files.  The reason for this post is to identify "why did the code cause files to remain open".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should close the `Stream` when done. From the Javadoc of [`Files.list`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)):

> The returned stream contains a reference to an open directory. The directory is closed by closing the stream.

Example:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(directory)) {
    // use the stream...
}
```

Comment: Applied this solution and redeployed to tomcat.  Solution works.  Thank you.